# C++ - polymorphism: cannot use function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I cannot find the answer, so maybe someone will be able to help me. I don't understand why I can't call ptr->other(). THX

```
class A
{
public:
  A(){}
  virtual ~A(){}
  virtual void fun(){ cout<<"fun A"<<endl;}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
  B(){}
  ~B(){}
  virtual void fun(){ cout<<"fun B"<<endl;}
  void other(){cout<<"other fuction"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
  A *ptr = new B();
  ptr->fun();
  ptr->other(); //it doesn't work :(
}
```

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to `A` and `A` doesn't have `other()`. It doesn't matter what it actually points to.

Comment: `A` doesn't have an `other()` member function. In this case, it actually points to a `B`, but not all `A*` point to a `B`.

Comment: So I need to cast the pointer (only this solution will work?)

Answer (score 3):

That is not the way polymorphism is supposed to be used.

You can indeed assign a `B*` to a `A*`, but all the time that you use a pointer to `A`, you can only use members belonging to `A`.

If you have a pointer to `A` and need to use a member of `B`, you must first downcast the pointer. You can use a `static_cast` is you know that the pointer does point to a `B` object, or a `dynamic_cast` if you want to have a chance to control that:

```
B* pb = static_cast<B *>(ptr); // unconditional cast
pb->other();                   // undefined behaviour if ptr does not point to a B object
```

but

```
B* pb = dynamic_cast<B *>(ptr);  // pb will be null if ptr does not point to a B object
if (pb != nullptr) pb->other();     // perfectly defined behaviour
```

Comment: `NULL`? What is this, 1998? ;)

Comment: @Quentin Well I learned C in the 80's and C++ in the early 90'... Updated. And thank you for noticing

Comment: Thank You tooo :-) now I will try to do this with smart pointers :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not suppose to work because `other()` is not defined in A.

In your example the function `fun()` is correct way of using polymorphism, it needs to be defined in base class and overridden in derived class. It is not the case with `other()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use have to implicitly tell that the ptr belongs to an object B since ptr used a B constructor :

```
((B*)(ptr))->other();
```

Comment: Please use a `static_cast` or a `dynamic_cast` rather than the landmine that a C-style cast is.

Comment: B *ptr2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr);
    ptr2->other();

Answer (score 0):

C++ is statically typed, and `ptr` is an `A *`. When you call `ptr->fun`, the compiler sees that `A` has a virtual `fun` and uses what's called a virtual function table to find `B::fun` at run time. When you call `ptr->other`, the compiler sees that `A` has no `other` at all, so that's an error. That's why you have to use a `static_cast` to tell the compiler to look in `B` first.